# ListBox control shows empty screen while moving up and down wards using Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox, virtualization

We are developing chat application, in that chat page is having listBox.  If that listbox has 100's of records the page will become blank if we scroll up and down. I heard about list box whatever items we are seeing remaining items will be clear. And I used VirtualizationMode="Standard" and "Recycling" but no use.  Please help me on this issue.

Comment: why dont you try the LongListSelector, i feel it would be apt for your scenario : http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/05/23/windows-phone-8-xaml-longlistselector.aspx

Comment: Ofcourse but my problem with LongListSelector does have check boxes for multi selection, I don't need that one.Here listBox multi selection is quite good than LongListSelector...

Comment: And even LongListSelector some times shows blank page without records, may those are loading every time...@Abhilash

Comment: I agree with you, there is LongListMultiSelector in windowsphone toolkit for multiselection if you want to give it a shot, http://phone.codeplex.com/, but it may have bugs/roadblocks i encountered a couple of them, can help if you provide some sample or more detail

Comment: I already used LongListSelector in another page there itself am getting the page without records if we do scroll up and down...@Abhilash

Comment: Are you facing this issue on WP7? Also, in your item, are you displaying images? If possible don't use ListBox at all. Always user LongListSelector. You can disable the checkBoxes.

Comment: @op_amp I need multiple selection, so I need LongListMultiSelector in that we are getting checkBoxes we can't disable them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After done by some research, using ItemsControl my problem got solved..